# Installing aws eb cli on Mac OS

Tags: bash, macos, amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I follow the instructions from here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-install.html

This pip install --upgrade --user awsebcli ran fine but when I type $ eb

it says command not found.

Apparently I must modify path variable:

echo $SHELL. gives me: /bin/bash.

Here are the instructions:

```
1) Find your shell's profile script in your user folder. If you are not sure which shell you have, run echo $SHELL.

$ ls -a ~
.  ..  .bash_logout  .bash_profile  .bashrc  Desktop  Documents  Downloads
Bash – .bash_profile, .profile, or .bash_login.
Zsh – .zshrc
Tcsh – .tcshrc, .cshrc or .login.

2) Add an export command to profile script.

export PATH=~/.local/bin:$PATH
This command adds a path, `~/.local/bin` in this example, to the current PATH variable.

3) Load the profile into your current session.

$ source ~/.bash_profile
```

This doesn't make any sense to me: why should i run `$ ls -a ~` ? I ran

```
export PATH=~/.local/bin:$PATH
```

and it didn't change anything. Same for 3.

Please advise on how to get eb working. Thanks.

UPDATE:echo $PATH gives me:

/Users/ME/bin/bash:/Users/ME/bin/bash.:/Users/ME/.local/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/usr/local/mysql-5.7.11-osx10.9-x86_64/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/Users/ME/.local/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/usr/local/mysql-5.7.11-osx10.9-x86_64/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet

Comment: What does `echo $PATH` output?

Comment: Please see updated answer

Comment: `~/.local/bin` is just an example. For OSX, it is different. Check the instructions again. I suggest you just do `$ brew install awsebcli` which takes care of everything.

Comment: Thanks it fixed it with brew. You can add this as an answer. Why does brew take care of this and not the other way ? Is brew smarter when it comes to those procedures ?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Use:

```
$ brew install awsebcli
```

as described in: [Install the EB CLI on OS X](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-install-osx.html)

Homebrew is specifically for OSX and handles dependencies well.

Answer (score 3):

- If you are trying to install EB CLI for default python version on mac, you can simply use:

  ```
  $brew install awsebcli
  ```
- If you are intending to install for python3, use pip3 to install and add export path to the bash profile as you mentioned. The path should be directed to the bin of python3 installed on your mac.

  *Example:*

  ```
  export PATH=~/Library/Python/3.7/bin:$PATH
  ```

For more details, refer:
https://medium.com/@stevo.perisic/installing-python3-pip-and-aws-cli-on-macos-sierra-ca23ff8ad651

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way for mac users is to use homebrew

```
brew install awsebcli
```

An alternative that worked for me:

1. Clone this repository
   Use the following:

```
git clone https://github.com/aws/aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli-setup.git
```

2. Install/Upgrade the EB CLI
   MacOS/Linux
   On Bash or Zsh:

```
python ./aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli-setup/scripts/ebcli_installer.py
```

Windows
In PowerShell or in a Command Prompt window:

```
python .\aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli-setup\scripts\ebcli_installer.py
```

3. After installation
   On Linux and macOS, the output contains instructions to add the EB CLI (and Python) executable file to the shell's $PATH variable, if it isn't already in it.

3.1 Usage
The `ebcli_installer.py` Python script will install the awsebcli package in a virtual environment to prevent potential conflicts with other Python packages.

For most use cases you can execute the `ebcli_installer.py` script with no arguments.

```
python ./aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli-setup/scripts/ebcli_installer.py
```

More information can be gotten [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli-setup)